# Invalid version string 'GNU/Linux'" when creating bootable USB stick

Tags: ubuntu, usb

When I tried to create a bootable USB stick using Startup Disk Creator, appear this massege below.

Invalid version string 'GNU/Linux'"

[image]

How can I create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: For which OS did you are  trying to create bootable USB disk ?

Comment: I don't know Startup Disk Creator well, but did you enter that string manually? If so, then the slash `(/)` can cause the error. Try eg. `ubuntu` instead.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried create a Debian 7 32 bits.

Comment: try unetbootin :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for this, is to use `dd` like this

```
dd if=/path/to/debian.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Is necessary to burn the image to the entire usb and not just the first partition, sdc, not sdc1.